# How to delete everything after a word in vim

Tags: regex, vim, replace

so i have this string

```
Animal Elephant
Animal Giraffe
Animal Chicken
Animal Duck
Animal Cow
```

i want to use vim and get the output like below.

```
Elephant
Giraffe
Chicken
Duck
Cow
```

The closest thing that I have to do is using

```
:%s/Animal.*//
```

But I don't get output that I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your file using vim as below:-

`vim <FILE_NAME>`

and inside use the below command to replace all `Animal`  string with empty string

`:%s/Animal //g`

This will remove all your `Animal`  string with empty string, then you can save the file and exit.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command:

```
:%norm dw
```